# Writing a Copy Method for a Class in OOP

Tags: java, oop, copy

Say I have a **Class of Car**, here is its code:

```
public class Car {
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private int year;

    public Car()
    {
        this.make = "";
        this.model = "";
        this.year = 0;
    }

    public Car(Car c)
    {
        this.make = c.getMake();
        this.model = c.getModel();
        this.year = c.getYear();
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    /* Trouble here */
    public Car copy(Car c)
    {
        return c; // But needs all properties to be same as current instance of class.
    }

}
```

Note that I do not have Setter methods for my private fields. Is there a way that I can have a `Copy(Car c)` *method that would copy my instance into a target object of the same type and return the target object?*

Without adding the Setters methods.

Comment: You've tagged your question 'java', but in your title, you wrote 'C#'. So what language do you use?

Comment: Sorry, the question was a general OOP one :)

Comment: Language-specific details such as which code can access what and where are language-specific.

Comment: Oh, in that case it is Java, sorry did not know that.

Comment: Why do you want to? What are you really trying to do? Copying a simple immutable object isn't that useful; use the one you have.

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything, just wanted to know if it can be done without setter methods in place and where fields are private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Car copy(Car c)
{
    c.make = this.make;
    c.model = this.model;
    c.year = this.year;
    return c; // But needs all properties to be same as current instance of class.
}
```

Comment: The method is internal to class Car, it have access to private fields.

Comment: Hmm, this point skipped me, let me give it a try a get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically done by using a [Copy Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), which you have already implemented.

```
Car car = new Car();
Car copiedCar = new Car(car);
```

If you'd like to use a method to perform this, you can call the copy constructor from inside the method.

```
public Car copy(Car c)
{
    Car copiedCar = new Car(c);
    return copiedCar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access control works by by scope; code in the `Car` class can access all of the private attributes of all `Car` instances no matter where they come from.

```
public Car copy(Car c)
{
    c.make = this.make;
    c.model = this.model;
    c.year = this.year;
    return c;
}
```